# ¿Cómo limitar los procesos hijo de PHP?

Tags: php, php7, hilos

Tengo un script PHP que crea unos 50 procesos hijos. Todos estos procesos se ejecutan en simultáneo, por lo que están consumiendo casi todos mis recursos (espacio en disco, RAM y principalmente CPU).

He intentado optimizarlo, pero es imposible, creo que la única forma es controlar los procesos hijos para:

- Limitar los recursos que utiliza cada proceso
- Limitar la cantidad a 10 procesos y cuando finalice uno se ejecuté otro.

Actualmente el código es el siguiente:

```
$parent_pid = getmypid();
foreach($competitors as $competitor)
{
    if(getmypid() == $parent_pid) //Si estamos en el proceso padre
    {
        $pid = pcntl_fork(); //Creo un proceso hijo
        if($pid == 0) //Si es hijo
        {
            //Mi lógica
            register_shutdown_function(create_function('$pars', 'posix_kill(getmypid(), SIGKILL);'), array());
            exit();
        }
    }
}
while(pcntl_waitpid(0, $status) != -1); //Después que mueran todos los hijos
```

**¿Cómo podría poner a la espera los 40 procesos hijos restantes, y detectar cuando uno finalice para que en la cola de espera queden 39 y así sucesivamente?**

Comment: Eso tiene toda la pinta de requerir un sistema de colas. Defines una cola de tareas a atender y los vas atendiendo de acuerdo a tu lógica.

Comment: gracias por responder tan rápido, ¿serías tan amable de darme un ejemplo sencillo?

Comment: Esta es una pregunta algo vieja pero que da una idea de las opciones disponibles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149291/how-to-build-a-php-queue-system

Comment: También podrías usar lo que sugieren acá https://stackoverflow.com/a/44654058/236345

Comment: Lo voy a ver, nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: Parece bastante compleja la instalación de todos los que he visto, no he podido con ninguno. ¿Cuál me podrías recomendar que sea fácil de instalar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> No lo he probado en producción

La verdad es que en internet hay muy, pero muy poca información sobre las multitareas de PHP o procesamiento en parelelo, esto es tal, que no encontré información en español y ni siquiera vídeos en youtube.

La solución (probada en entornos de prueba) ha sido la siguiente:

```
<?php
declare(ticks = 1); //Esto es obligatorio

$max=10; //Número máximo de procesos que quieres
$child=0;

//Esta función se llama automáticamente cuando un hijo muere (resta -1 a los procesos actuales)
// function for signal handler
function sig_handler($signo) {
  global $child;
  switch ($signo) {
    case SIGCHLD:
      echo "SIGCHLD received\n";
      $child -= 1; 
  }
}

// install signal handler for dead kids
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, "sig_handler");

for ($i=1;$i<=20;$i++) {
        //Cada 5 segundos te intentará crear un hijo
        while ($child >= $max) {
                sleep(5); echo "\t Maximum children allowed\n";
                }
        $child++;
        $pid=pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid == -1) {
                die("could not fork");
        } else if ($pid) {
                // we are the parent
        } else {
                // we are the child
                //Acá va el código del proceso hijo
                exit;
        }
}
```

Fuente: [pcntl php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcntl.php)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en tu caso en lugar de utilizar colas de mensajeria, seria mas bien comprobar el estado de la memoria ANTES de crear un proceso hijo. Podrias hacerlo con parte de este codigo:

```
$startMemory = memory_get_usage();
$array = range(1, 100000); // esto lo cambias por el codigo de tu proceso hijo
echo memory_get_usage() - $startMemory, ' bytes';
```

`memory_get_usage` te da la información de cuanta memoria esta ocupada en el proceso principal. Si supera una cantidad que tu consideres / tengas precalculada, no dejas crear procesos hijo.

Tambien puedes revisar las funciones de tamaño de disco actual con

```
$ds = disk_total_space("/");
```

`disk_total_space` te da el espacio que queda en el directorio indicado. Lo del directorio hace referencia realmente a la particion (en linux podrias tener montado un disco duro en un directorio especifico)

Comment: Gracias! pero ¿cómo creo una lógica que siga chequeando la memoria hasta que la se libere total o parcialmente, y una vez hecho eso se creen los procesos hijo que previamente no se crearon?. Lo que intento decir es que, deben ejecutarse todos los procesos hijos, no de forma simultanea como ha sido hasta ahora, sino que se ejecuten unos 10, luego otro 10, etc. ¿Cómo lo hago?